# How do you find all of the subsequences of a list?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn how to list comprehension and I'm trying to figure out a way to find all the subsequences of a list but i'm not quite sure how one would go about that. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 18):

If you want access to this functionality, you can use the `subsequences` function that is in `Data.List`.

```
subsequences [1,2,3]
>>> [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

---

If you want to know how it's implemented, you can check the function's [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#subsequences), which is available on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/).

In this case, it's:

```
subsequences            :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsequences xs         =  [] : nonEmptySubsequences xs

nonEmptySubsequences         :: [a] -> [[a]]
nonEmptySubsequences []      =  []
nonEmptySubsequences (x:xs)  =  [x] : foldr f [] (nonEmptySubsequences xs)
  where f ys r = ys : (x : ys) : r
```

Comment: Note: `f ys r = ys : (x : ys) : r` - here's the part where you can see it is considering all substrings for the string `xs` (the tail of the input), then deciding both to include and exclude `x` (the head of the input) for each of those that exist. Recursion does this for every tail of the list until you hit the empty string, bubbles back up, and bam, you're done.

Comment: @DanBurton dear can you explain to me who f ys r = ys : (x : ys) : r works? I didn't understand what ys and r?

Answer (score 18):

Just another interesting solution:

```
filterM (const [True,False]) [1,2,3]
```

I read this as follows: Return the possible combinations of including or not including an element of the list. This explanation might not be using the correct terminology, but it's how I intuitively understand it. `const` evaluates to `[True,False]` for every element, so every element is included or not included in the result. Using `filterM`, the predicate here is in the list monad, so we get a list of the possible results.

Comment: Please notice, that the order of the resulting list may vary.

Comment: Your solution is really great (I'm really impressed with its succintness), but using such conundrums in a library code may be not a good thing. Though YMMV.

Comment: @EarlGray, thanks, and I agree that there are probably more easily understandable solutions to include in one's projects. (That's why I wrote "just another interesting solution") Then again, a type signature would surely improve intelligibility a bit.

Answer (score 13):

Ezra's answer covers all subsequences, but if you just want the continuous sub-sequences, you can use:

```
import Data.List
continuousSubSeqs = filter (not . null) . concatMap inits . tails
```

I.e you get

```
Prelude Data.List> continuousSubSeqs "asdf"
["a","as","asd","asdf","s","sd","sdf","d","df","f"]
```

The above can be written as a list comprehension as well:

```
import Data.List
continuousSubSeqs ls = [t | i <- inits ls, t <- tails i, not $ null t]
```

Comment: or even `continuousSubSeqs ls = [t | i <- inits ls, t@(_:_) <- tails i]`. flipping the `inits` call with the `tails` call gets somewhat more natural ordering of subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the answer by @danlei for it's expressiveness (if you understand the non-determinism introduced by lists).  But you don't need Monads for this.  There is an applicative solution which also has that expressiveness while returning results in exactly the same order as the **foldr** based solution in the Data.List library.

```
subs [] = [[]]
subs (x:xs) = subs xs <**> [id, (x :)]
```

For me, once you understand how lists provide non-determinism (for which they much more powerful and useful than they are as a simple data structure), this is more immediately understandable than the **foldr** implementation.

It has two other interesting features compared to the library code:

1. It is simple to change it to replace **:** with any monoidal function (or to make it generic so that it can work with any monoid).
2. Also simple to change it to work with any foldable for which there is also a monoid instance (although any foldable has **toList**, so that's minor).

(Of course, the Data.List implementation, by using **foldr**, avoids external dependencies)

For example...

```
xorSubs [] = [0]
xorSubs (x:xs) = xorSubs xs <**> [id, xor x]
```

will efficiently calculate **xor** for all subsequences of a list. If a list contains multiple subsequences beginning with **1 : 2** (but only one instance of **1** and **2**), **xor 1 2** is calculated once and that value shared with all subsequences which contain **1 : 2**.  That is much more efficient than folding **xor** over each list in the output of **subsequences**.

Since **0** would be **mempty** for a monoid instance of **xor**, it shouldn't be hard to see how you could rewrite it as

```
msubs :: Monoid a => [a] -> [a]
```