# Linking in tree structures

Tags: haskell, suffix-tree

Upon working with long strings now, I came across a rather big problem in creating suffix trees in Haskell.

Some constructing algorithms (as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english) version of Ukkonen's algorithm) require establishing links between nodes. These links "point" on a node in the tree. In imperative languages, such as Java, C#, etc. this is no problem because of reference types.

Are there ways of emulating this behaviour in Haskell? Or is there a completely different alternative?

Comment: When all else fails, you can write your stateful algorithm with `ST` and `STRef`s. You can then `runST` to get your pure suffix tree at the end.

Comment: Why Ukkonen's algorithm is so popular recently in Haskell tag, There are another question, without a proper answer though - only hints in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370296/haskell-data-type-with-references

Comment: Do you need just directed acyclic graphs? You can use graphs from [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl) package.

Comment: One standard trick to construct self-referential structures is called "tying the knot." You may find the answers to this question helpful: [How do you represent a graph in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732084/how-do-you-represent-a-graph-in-haskell).

Comment: Oh, and there's an [unanswered question on a similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370296/haskell-data-type-with-references) that has a few comments you may find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a value that isn't determined until the result of a computation in the construction of data in the computation by [tying a recursive knot](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot).

The following computation builds a list of values that each hold the total number of items in the list even though the total is computed by the same function that's building the list. The `let` binding in `zipCount` passes one of the results of `zipWithAndCount` as the first argument to `zipWithAndCount`.

```
zipCount :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]
zipCount xs = 
    let (count, zipped) = zipWithAndCount count xs
    in zipped

zipWithAndCount :: Num n => b -> [a] -> (n, [(a, b)])
zipWithAndCount y [] = (0, [])
zipWithAndCount y (x:xs) =
    let (count', zipped') = zipWithAndCount y xs
    in (count' + 1, (x, y):zipped')
```

Running this example makes a list where each item holds the count of the total items in the list

```
> zipCount ['a'..'e']
[('a',5),('b',5),('c',5),('d',5),('e',5)]
```

This idea can be applied to [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513423/414413) by passing in the `#`s that aren't known until the entire result is known.

The general idea of recursively passing a result into a function is called a least fixed point, and is implemented in `Data.Function` by

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

We can write `zipCount` in points-free style in terms of `zipWithAndCount` and `fix`.

```
import Data.Function

zipCount :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]
zipCount = snd . fix . (. fst) . flip zipWithAndCount
```