# All subsequences from a single string

Tags: haskell

How do you extract every possible substring from a single string? 
I have come up with a kind of cumbersome way and want to find a simpler one.

```
subStrings :: String -> [String]
subStrings xs = xs : takeEl xs

takeEl :: String -> [String]
takeEl xs = nub (concat [y : (takeEl y) | y <- takeEl'])
  where 
    takeEl' = [del y xs | y <- [0..(length xs - 1)]]

del :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
del k xs = take k xs ++ drop (k+1) xs
```

I would like to explain a little further with an example:
if I use the function on  "abc", I want it to create a list including the elements below, with no permutations (if "ab" is there "ba" is not necessary).

```
`["abc", "a","b","c","ab","ac","bc",""]`
```

So concat inits . tails will not be enough since it won't give me "ac".

Comment: `concatMap inits (tails xs)` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find all of the subsequences of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373927/how-do-you-find-all-of-the-subsequences-of-a-list)

Answer (score 5):

The `Data.List` module offers [`subsequences`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences), which is the correct name for this. (Substrings are contiguous.)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**  The following computes **substrings**, which was mentioned in the original question, not **subsequences**.

---

If you're looking for something quick (and not necessarily as efficient as possible), here's what I would suggest:

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

nonEmptySubstrings :: [a] -> [[a]]
nonEmptySubstrings = concatMap (tail . inits) . tails
```

The `tail` is needed to eliminate the empty substring altogether; it would otherwise occur multiple times.  If you want it too, you'll have to add it extra.

```
substrings :: [a] -> [[a]]
substrings = ([] :) . nonEmptySubstrings
```

Example:

```
Prelude Data.List> nonEmptySubstrings "abcd"
["a","ab","abc","abcd","b","bc","bcd","c","cd","d"]
Prelude Data.List> substrings "abcd"
["","a","ab","abc","abcd","b","bc","bcd","c","cd","d"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by taking the possible heads of all tails, or all possible tails of all heads.

This works since all substrings are uniquely determined by 2 things, position and length. When you drop all possible heads with `tails`, you're taking the string starting from every possible position with the longest possible length, then applying `inits` to all of these returns all possible lengths, combining these gives all possible substrings. The idea for the reverse is trivially similar.

So you can use nickie's

```
concatMap inits . tails
```

Or

```
concatMap tails . inits
```

And since `>>=` is the same as `concatMap`, you could write

```
tails <=< inits -- From control.monad
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you're after isn't the list of all subsequences, but the list of all subsets (keeping the original order) - a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset). This can be accomplished by a nice trick in the list monad:

```
filterM (const [False, True]) "abc"
```

yields

```
["","c","b","bc","a","ac","ab","abc"]
```

The trick is that we non-deterministically filter the given list in the list monad, branching to both keep and remove a particular element.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `["","abc","a","b","c","ab","ac","bc","abc"]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use functions outside Prelude, use this:

```
substrings x = [drop b (take a x) | a <- [1..length x], b <- [0..a-1]]
```

This is definitely not the most efficient method. Just a quick and dirty one-liner for performance-insensitive tasks

However, OP's original question meant [subsequences](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences) and not substrings.

Comment: a > b means a < b isn't it? and instead of testing and rejecting we can generate only the valid `b`s in the first place.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the code to generate only valid `b`s. Also, since we're taking `a` letters of `x` and dropping the first `b` letters, a>b, not the other way round.